# Examples of Zsh alternate forms of complex commands

Tags: zsh

Would you please provide an insight on [Alternate Forms For Complex Commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands)?

I spent a very long time on this document, but it could be made clearer.

I am looking for clear examples for `if`, `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `until`, `repeat`, `case`, `select`, and `function`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are just shorter forms of some commands, mainly getting rid of "redundant" reserved words like `then`, `fi`, `do`, `done`, etc. Long formats are more portable; short ones work exclusively in `zsh`.

---

For example long form of `if`

```
if [[ -f file ]] ; then echo "file exists"; else echo "file does not exist"; fi
```

will work not only in `zsh` but also in other shells (replace double brackets with single ones to gain even more portability)

Whereas short formats

```
if [[ -f file ]] { echo "file exists" } else { echo "file does not exist" }
if [[ -f file ]] echo file exists
```

works only in `zsh`.

---

Another example, this time with `for` loop.

Long formats:

```
for char in a b c; do echo $char; done
for (( x=0; x<3; x++ )) do echo $x; done
```

Short:

```
for char in a b c; echo $char
for char (a b c) echo $char             # second version of the same
foreach char (a b c); echo $char; end   # csh-like 'for' loop
for (( x=0; x<3; x++ )) echo $x         # c++ version
for (( x=0; x<3; x++ )) { echo "$x"; }  # also works in bash and ksh
```

---

I believe you get the idea - we just remove unnecessary words, and if lists need to be separated from the other stuff embrace them with `{}`. The rest of commands:

- while

  ```
  x=0; while ((x<3)); do echo $((x++)); done    # long
  x=0; while ((x<3)) { echo $((x++)) }          # short
  x=0; while ((x<3)) echo $((x++))              # shorter for single command
  ```
- until

  ```
  x=0; until ((x>3)); do echo $((x++)); done    # long
  x=0; until ((x>3)) { echo $((x++)) }          # short
  x=0; until ((x>3)) echo $((x++))              # shorter for single command
  ```
- repeat

  ```
  repeat 3; do echo abc; done                   # long
  repeat 3 echo abc                             # short
  ```
- case

  ```
  word=xyz; case $word in abc) echo v1;; xyz) echo v2;; esac   # long
  word=xyz; case $word { abc) echo v1;; xyz) echo v2 }         # short
  ```
- select

  ```
  select var in a b c; do echo $var; done       # long
  select var in a b c; echo $var                # short
  select var (a b c) echo $var                  # shorter
  ```
- function

  ```
  function myfun1 { echo abc; }            # long
  function myfun2; echo abc                # short
  myfun3() echo abc                        # shorter and Bourne-compatible
  ```

Comment: For begginer guide, can you do verbose all the commands, even get the idea, it's help for newbie.

Comment: See also [What is the purpose of the "do" keyword in Bash for loops?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/306944) for various forms of `for` loops supported by different Bourne-like shells.