# About Precommand Modifiers in zsh

Tags: zsh, shell-builtin

### Background

While the [zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Shell-Grammar) (ch 6.2) provides a description for what **precommand modifiers** can do, it fails to provide examples for each type: `-`, `builtin`, `command`, `exec`, `nocorrect`, and `noglob`.

There is a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468582/362339) asked by user [Tuyen Pham](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/256195/tuyen-pham). However, that question does not put emphasis on requesting an example for each type of precommand modifier.

---

### Issue

Can anyone provide examples for what each precommand modifier can do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that I'm giving a single example for each modifier below.  Some, like `exec` and `command`, have multiple uses besides what's shown here.

---

- Using `-` to run a utility would insert a dash as the first character of its zeroth argument (the command name).  A dash as the first character of the command name is a common way to signal to a shell that it should initialize as a login shell.

  ```bsh
  # Start the yash shell as a login shell:
  - yash
  ```

  This may make the shell that you start read a different set of startup scripts.  In the case of `yash`, it would read the `~/.yash_profile` file first, which it would not otherwise do, for example.

  When a shell is started with `-` as the first character of `$0`, it will be a login shell. The login shell would commonly also have an `l` (lower-case ell) in `$-` (although the `bash` shell does not seem to follow this custom):

  ```bsh
  $ sh -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$-"'
  sh
  ch
  ```

  ```bsh
  $ - sh -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$-"'
  -sh
  clh
  ```
- With `builtin`, you ensure that the command that you run is the built-in variant of the command and not e.g. an external command, alias or shell function:

  ```bsh
  builtin cd mydir
  ```

  This may be useful if you, for example, would want to write a shell function called `cd` that, as part of what it did, called the built-in variant of `cd` to actually change working directory.  Using just `cd` would cause a recursive call to your function.

  ```bsh
  $ cd () { builtin cd "$@" && printf 'Now in %s\n' $PWD; }
  $ cd /tmp
  Now in /tmp
  ```
- The `command` command is [a standard POSIX command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) that may, for example, be used to determine whether a particular utility exists on the system in the user's current `PATH`:

  ```bsh
  if ! command -v gsed >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo 'gsed is not available'
  fi
  ```

  The `command` command is often also used to disable alias and function lookups for the given utility, in a way similar to what I showed for `builtin` above.
- The `exec` keyword is [also standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec), and may be used to completely *replace* the current shell with another process:

  ```bsh
  # Replace the shell with bash
  exec bash
  ```

  Typing `exit` after this would not take you back to the original shell session, as it was replaced by the `bash` shell session.

  You would also use `exec` to set up redirections for the current shell's standard I/O streams.
- If the current interactive shell session has spelling correction enabled (`setopt CORRECT`), using `nocorrect` would *not* enable correction for the command.

  Ordinarily:

  ```bsh
  $ setopt CORRECT
  $ seed
  zsh: correct 'seed' to 'sed' [nyae]? n
  zsh: command not found: seed
  ```

  With `nocorrect`:

  ```bsh
  $ setopt CORRECT
  $ nocorrect seed
  zsh: command not found: seed
  ```
- The `noglob` modifier disables globbing for the current command:

  ```bsh
  $ noglob echo *
  *
  ```

  Without the `noglob` modifier, the `*` pattern would have been expanded and the generated words (the filenames in the current directories) would have been given as arguments to `echo`.

  In other shells, one could turn off globbing temporarily with `set -f`, and then turn it on again with `set +f`.  This would be [the standard way](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) to disable filename globbing in the shell. The `set -f` command does not affect globbing in `zsh`, unless the shell is emulating `sh` or `ksh`.

Comment: `zsh`'s `command` predates POSIX `command` and is not the same (except in `sh` emulation) as POSIX' one. It runs the given (external) command from the filesystem, while in POSIX' `command` it's only used to bypass functions (and disable the special behaviours of special builtins). `command echo` in POSIX `sh` still runs the builtin `echo`. That's why in `zsh`, you need `cd() { builtin cd...; }`. `cd() { command cd...; }` won't work. Note that `yash` has `command -e` as the equivalent of zsh's `command`